# Handle "return" key in MobileSafari javascript prompt() dialog?

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, mobile-safari, prompt

In desktop Safari (and basically every other desktop browser), hitting "return" to while a prompt() dialog is displayed is the same as clicking "OK". In my experiments with bookmarklets for MobileSafari, though, I've found that it just defocuses the text field (and hides the keyboard). This is verified in iOS 5.0.1 on both iPhone and iPad, and I believe it behaved that way on at least some versions of 4.x as well.

How do I make "return" activate "OK"?

Answer (score 0):

Using a  tag and binding your handler to the submit tag.

```
$("#myForm").submit(function (event) 
{
   doStuff();
}
);
```